# Operator precedence in c with %,!=,= and ','

Tags: c

In code snippet below

```
int jo=50;
if( jo =(rand()%100), jo!=50)
{
    printf("!50");
}
```

1. % has highest precedence so rand()%100 will get executed first
2. != has the precedence greater than = so jo != 50 should get execute right ?
3. , has the least precedence
   still when i execute assignment occurs first then != and then , . I get an output !50 why ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is "sequence points":

> http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/VSJ/SequencePoints/SequencePoints.html
>
> **Problematic vs. Safe Expressions**
>
> What is it that renders the
> assignment x[i]=i++ + 1; a problematic one whereas the assignment
> i=2; is harmless, in the sense that its result is well-defined and
> predictable?  The crux is that in the expression x[i]=i++ + 1; there
> are two accesses to variable i and one of the accesses, namely the
> i++,  is a modifying access. Since the order of evaluation between
> sequence points is not defined we do not know whether i will be
> modified before it will be read or whether it will be read before the
> modification. Hence the root of the problem is multiple access to a
> variable between sequence points if one the accesses is a
> modification.
>
> Here is another example.  What will happen here if  i and j have
> values 1 and 2 before the statement is executed?
>
> ```
> f(i++, j++, i+j);
> ```
>
> Which value will be passed to function f as the third argument?
> Again, we don't know. It could be any of the following: 3, 4, or 5. It
> depends on the order in which the function arguments are evaluated.
> The common misconception here is that the arguments would be evaluated
> left to right. Or maybe right to left? In fact, there is no order
> whatsoever mandated by the language definition.

Comment: The issue is not sequence points.  The comma operator here introduces a sequence point; the example code is well-defined.

Answer (score 3):

Precedence does *not* control the order of execution.  Precedence only controls the grouping - that is, precedence says *what* the operands are for each operation, not *when* each operation happens.

In this example, the precedence of `%` is irrelevant due to the parentheses - these say that the operands of `%` are `rand()` and `100`.

The precedece of `,` being lower than that of `=` and `!=` tells us that the operands of `=` are `jo` and `(rand()%100)`, and that the operands of `!=` are `jo` and `50`.

The operands of `,` are then `jo = (rand() % 100)` and `jo != 50`.

The definition of the `,` operator says that the first operand is evaluated, then there is a sequence point, and then the second operand is evaluated.  So this case, `jo = (rand() % 100)` is fully evaluated, which stores the result of `rand() % 100` into `jo`; and then `jo != 50` is evaluated.  The value of the overall expression is the value of `jo != 50`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, sequence points is the right answer. but let's translate from the textbook-ese.

The comma operator has a special property: it makes sure that what's on its left hand side is evaluated first.  So, when you get to the expression

```
 jo =(rand()%100), jo!=50
```

*even though* the `!=` *binds* more tightly than ',', so that the expressiojn, fully parenthesized is

```
 (jo =(rand()%100)),(jo!=50)
```

the first part is *evaluated* first.

To remember this, you can pronouce or read the comma operator as "and then", so

```
 j0=(rand()%100)
```

"and then"

```
 jo!=50.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a mistake to think of "precedence" as "done first".

Consider the following code snippet:

```
f() + g() + h()
```

Which has add operation has higher precedence, the one that sums the results of f() and g(), or the one that sums the results of that and h()?

It's a trick question, because there is no need to invoke "precedence" at all.  But there is still an order of operations, because function calls in C introduce "sequence points", which is how C allows you to determine "what happens when", as it were.

In your particular code, you have a comma operator—which is quite different from the comma punctuator in function arguments—in this part:

```
jo = (rand() % 100), jo != 50
```

The comma operator introduces a sequence point (as does the function call to `rand`), so we know that `rand` runs and produces a value, then that value `% 100` is computed and assigned to `jo`, and finally `jo` is compared with `50`.

(There is a sequence point after the evaluation of the controlling expression in the `if` as well, and one at each statement-ending semicolon.)

Comment: There might well be a need to know the precedence (well, in this case associativity) of the `+` operators in your example.  Consider the case where `f() + g() + h()` does not overflow, but the intermediate result `g() + h()` might.  In this case it is important that the `f() + g()` is done first.

Comment: @caf: Yes!  Fortunately the word "associativity" does not resemble the word "precede", the way the word "precedence" does. :-)

Comment: Well asking whether an operator has higher or lower precendece than itself is always obviously a nonsense question, so that's why I assumed you meant associativity there.

Comment: That's why I called it a "trick question".  The idea is to make other person consider the difference between operator binding at parse time (during compilation), and eventual order of operations at run time.  The C language leaves run-time order at the discretion of the compiler, with exceptions determined primarily by sequence points (though as you note, some rearrangements are constrained in the presence of things like overflow).